# How to read file from assets folder in react-native?

Tags: react-native

I have some data in `android\app\src\main\assets` and I am using [rn-fetch-blob](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob) as filesystem.

But what is the schema path to `assets` folder in android? How to read data from it?

Is there any other way to ship pre pupolate data file in react-native ? Can I place file in react-native project root directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is [readFileAssets](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs#readfileassetsfilepathstring-encoding-string-promisestring) is a method in [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs).

Place your file in `android\app\src\main\assets`.If there is no `assets` folder
then just create it.

```
import fs from "react-native-fs";

fs.readFileAssets("folder/file", "base64") // 'base64' for binary 
  .then(binary => {
    // work with it
  })
  .catch(console.error)
```

Note: Path must be relative. If `android\app\src\main\assets\folder\file` then use `folder\file`

Comment: It should work with iOS, see [doc](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs#usage-ios)

Answer (score 0):

> let path = RNFetchBlob.fs.asset('my-asset.jpg')

```
RNFetchBlob.fs.asset('bundle-assets://my-asset.jpg');
```

There is a method in doc [assetfilenamestrings](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob/wiki/File-System-Access-API#assetfilenamestringstring)