# How to load a saved Machine Learning model in React-Native? (for Android/iOS)

Tags: react-native

I wish to leverage a machine learning model in React-Native mobile app. The issue I have is I could not find a cross-platform method to bundle the machine learning model into the app and have the app load the model to be used.

For more context, I'm using `onnxruntime-react-native` to load a Machine Learning model in `.onnx` format. I'm trying to use the ONNX runtime to load the model when the app starts and use it for inference.

What I have tried is using the `react-native-assets` package and use `readDirAssets` method, but this is for Android only.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs). With `react-native-fs` you can get different paths in the filesystem and I think you need to get your `MainBundlePath`. However, you need to play with different path because the implementation of [InferenceSessionFactory.create](https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/blob/main/js/common/lib/inference-session.ts#L344) doesn't specify any formats.

```js
RNFS.readDir(RNFS.MainBundlePath) // On Android, use "RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath" (MainBundlePath is not defined)
  .then((result) => {
    console.log('GOT RESULT', result);

    // stat the first file
    return Promise.all([RNFS.stat(result[0].path), result[0].path]);
  })
```

Comment: It works for IOS, but how about android?

Comment: on android use `RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath` instead of `RNFS.MainBundlePath`

Comment: Yes, but it didn't see my onnx file. The onnx file under the main>assets

Comment: @İlker try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64421090/how-to-read-file-from-assets-folder-in-react-native